# gradient of TV norm in total variation denoising

Tags: image, optimization, gradient

In the link:
http://www.numerical-tours.com/matlab/denoisingsimp_4_denoiseregul/
It says that the gradient is as follow
[image]

From another link, 
http://image-processing-is-fun.blogspot.tw/2012/07/rudin-osher-fatemi-image-denoising-model.html
It also mentions that the derivative is as follow
[image]

I know how to calculate divergence, but I don't understand how the gradient of total variation is related to divergence.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. As I understood, Total Variation denoise the image by minimizing a functional F as in the first link:

```
        F = 1/2 (||y-f||^2) + lambda J(f)
```

the first term is the error or the difference between the noisy input image f and the result image y.

The second term is smoothing function J

we keep smoothing the image but try to not make it differ from the original image.

To minimize the functional above we use gradient descent:
 y = y - alpha  * F'
When you compute the derivative of F i.e. F' you get the divergence.
Here is more examples :
http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~nega0024/docs/2263_S14/GaussExamples.pdf

Comment: My question is that how the derivative is related to the divergence. If I calculate the derivative from the definition, I can't get the formula. Maybe the reason is that the objective function is the integral.